# beforeRemove etc when using with-binding

Tags: knockout.js

I'm using a with-binding and a counter to show items from an array one at a time, like this `<div data-bind="with: items[NavigatorCounter()]">` The counter is used like a pagination. When increasing (or decreasing) the counter, it would be nice to have a sliding effect, like explained [here](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/animatedTransitions.html). In that example they do: `{ foreach: planetsToShow, beforeRemove: hidePlanetElement, afterAdd: showPlanetElement }` It would be nice to be able to write like this: `{ with: items, beforeRemove: onRemove, afterAdd: onAdd }`. Any suggestions on how this could be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a second observable array with a subscription... write into the second observable array whenever the nav counter changes by using the subscription.

Here's a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/brettwgreen/eq9e67uu/1/

View:

```
<div data-bind="template: { foreach: currentItems,
                            beforeRemove: hideElement,
                            afterAdd: showElement }">
<div data-bind="text: name"></div>
</div>
<br />
<button data-bind="click: goNext">Next</button>
```

ViewModel:

```
var vm = function (){
    var self = this;
    self.items = ko.observableArray([ {name: "Item 1"}, {name: "Item 2"}, {name: "Item 3"}]);
    self.currentItems = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.NavigatorCounter = ko.observable(0);
    self.goNext = function() {
        if (self.NavigatorCounter() === self.items().length-1) {
            self.NavigatorCounter(0);
        }
        else {
            self.NavigatorCounter(self.NavigatorCounter()+1);
        }
    };
    self.NavigatorCounter.subscribe(function() {
        self.currentItems.removeAll();
        self.currentItems.push(self.items()[self.NavigatorCounter()]);
    });
    self.showElement = function(elem) { if (elem.nodeType === 1) $(elem).hide().slideDown() }
    self.hideElement = function(elem) { if (elem.nodeType === 1) $(elem).slideUp(function() { $(elem).remove(); }) }
    }
    ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

Comment: I was thinking about something like this, but I'm pretty new to Knockout so I couldn't figure the details out. Thank you very much!